# Filter and collect nested collection elements using Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a collection of `Parent` objects and each has a collection of `Child` elements, for example:

```
public class Parent {
    private Collection<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
    private String type;
}
```

How would I use Java 8 functional programming to filter and collect together a collection of `Child` where the type is equal to 'A'?

I have attempted this with the following:

```
Collection<Child> filteredChildren = parents.stream()
                                        .forEach(p ->
                                            filteredChildren.addAll(p.getChildren().stream()
                                                          .filter(c -> c.getType().equals("A"))
                                                          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                        );
```

But I get the following error:

> Variable 'filteredChildren' initializer
>   'parents.stream() .forEach(p -> ...' is redundant less... (⌘F1)  This
>   inspection points out the cases where a variable value is never used
>   after its assignment, i.e.:  - the variable never gets read after
>   assignment OR  - the value is always overwritten with another
>   assignment before the next variable read OR  - the variable
>   initializer is redundant (for one of the above two reasons)

How do I filter the nested collections by type and collect them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's wrong to use `forEach` in your code for the terminal `Stream` operation, since it produces no output, so you can't assign it to the `filteredChildren` variable.

Use `flatMap` in order to get a flat `Stream` of all the `Child` instances (filtered by type) of all the `Parent` instances, and then collect to a `List`:

```
Collection<Child> filteredChildren = 
    parents.stream()
           .flatMap(p -> p.getChildren()
                          .stream()
                          .filter(c -> c.getType().equals("A")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is stream over the parents collection, flattening out their children and filtering those having `type` equal to `"A"`.

```
parents.stream()
    .map(Parent::getChildren)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(children -> "A".equals(children.getType()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```